# MappingException: No persister for - NHibernate - Persisting an Adapter

Tags: c#, nhibernate, persistence, nhibernate-mapping

Well, I googled a lot, and found the same advices all there (set hbm as Embedded Resource, add hbm at hibernate.cfg, etc..), and despite of them, I still not get it.

Let me explain: I wrote a Communication Dll for a ticket gate device, and there I have a configuration model class, that I use to configure that device through TCP/IP. But now, I have to persist this object on DB, so I wrote an Adapter inside my model which glues one into another. This way, I have an Adapter for my configuration model that have an ID, IncludedDate and so on. Let's see:

DeviceConf Model class:

```
public class DeviceConf : BaseModel // which have ID, IncludedDate, etc
{
    private TGCommHelper.Entities.Configuration.TicketGateConfig _conf;

    public TGCommHelper.Entities.Configuration.TicketGateConfig conf
    {
        get { return _conf; }
        private set { _conf = value; }
    }
    public DeviceConf()
    {
        conf = new TGCommHelper.Entities.Configuration.TicketGateConfig();
    }
    public DeviceConf(TGCommHelper.Entities.Configuration.TicketGateConfig config){
        conf = config;
    }

    public virtual string IP
    {
        get { return conf.IP; }
        set { conf.IP = value; }
    }

    public virtual string MAC_ADDR
    {
        get { return conf.MAC_ADDR; }
        set { conf.MAC_ADDR = value; }
    }

//... and so on.
}
```

DeviceConf.hbm.xml Mapping file:

```
    < hibernate-mapping assembly="TGPass.Model" namespace="TGPass.Model"
xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    < class name="DeviceConf" table="DeviceConfTbl">
        < id name="ID" column="ID">
            < generator class="identity" />
        < /id>
        < property name="IP">
            < column name="IP" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
        < /property>
        < property name="MAC_ADDR">
            < column name="MAC_ADDR" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
        < /property>
        < !-- and so on -->
    < /class>
< /hibernate-mapping>
```

Save Method:

```
public virtual void Create(T saveObj)
{
    using (var session = GetSession())
    {
        using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                session.Save(saveObj);
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With another model classes I have here, all things work nicely, but not with this one.
Every time I try to save this with Create method, NHibernate raises a MappingException with "No persister for TGPass.Model.DeviceConf"...

Where I'm doing it wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you show the excpetion? if possible the complete one? because this kind of exception is simply always related to the fact: 1) Not embedded resource 2) wrong dll 3) wrong suffix .hbm.xml...

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thank you so much! Your comment gave me the clue! I must be blind! haha! I found that all the other HBM mapping files were named *.hbm.xml, and only this one was named *.xml only (not *.hbm.xml), and I couldn't see that on exception dialogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness *(also based on my painful experience)*, there are mostly three reasons of this exception:

1. xml mapping file is NOT makred as **`Embedded Resource`**
2. xml file is not part of **.dll** which is configured as the mapping source `<mapping assembly="MyProject.Data" />` *(see [`<session-factory>`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-intro) configuration)*
3. xml file does not have the default suffix **`.hbm.xml`**

One of these is usually the culprit of the: *MappingException: No persister for...*