# Duplicate collection role mapping nHibernate - When trying to make one - many mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am learning nHibernate and I was trying one to many mapping. Here are the two tables Product and Product Type.

```
namespace NHibernateSample.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Category { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Discontinued { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here are my mapping XMLs

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="NHibernateSample"
               namespace="NHibernateSample.Models">

  <!-- more mapping info here -->
  <class name="Product">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Category" />
    <property name="Discontinued" />

    <bag name="ProductTypes">
      <key column="ProductID" />
      <one-to-many class="NHibernateSample.Models.ProductType,NHibernateSample" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Product type xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="NHibernateSample"
               namespace="NHibernateSample.Models">

  <!-- more mapping info here -->
  <class name="ProductType">
    <id name="ProductTypeID">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="ProductType1" column="ProductType"/>
    <property name="ProductID" />
    <many-to-one name="Product" class="Product">
      <column name="ProductID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The mappings are in the config

```
mapping assembly="NHibernateSample" />
```

When I try configuring and build session factory

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
m_SessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I get the error saying "Association references unmapped class: NHibernateSample.Models.ProductType" but I see the hbm file in the bin folder.

If I add the assembly explicitly,

```
Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(Product).Assembly;
cfg.AddAssembly(thisAssembly);
```

I get another error saying "Duplicate collection role mapping NHibernateSample.Models.Product.ProductTypes"

What am I doing wrong ? Is it not the way I should map the foreign keys ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your hbm.xml file is embedded resource http://stackoverflow.com/a/25291907/1679310?

Comment: @RadimKöhler I did it for one xml and forgot to do it for the other. Thank you
How can I add a Product type when I add a product for the above code

Comment: Product prod = new Product();
prod.Name = "Q3";
prod.Category = "Audi";
prod.Discontinued = false;
session.Save(prod);

Here I insert a product. I want to insert some ProductType to the database like

prod.ProductTypes = new ....
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue seems to be related to wrong setting of the .hbm.xml file.. which always must have *(see e.g. [MappingException: No persister for - NHibernate - Persisting an Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291907/1679310))*

- xml mapping file is NOT makred as **Embedded Resource**
- xml file is not part of .dll which is configured as the mapping source `<mapping assembly="MyProject.Data" />` (see  configuration)
- xml file does not have the default suffix .hbm.xml

The second question (in comment)

> Here I insert a product. I want to insert some ProductType to the
>   database like `prod.ProductTypes = new` .... How can I do that
>
> ```
> Product prod = new Product(); 
> prod.Name = "Q3"; prod.Category = "Audi"; 
> prod.Discontinued = false; 
> session.Save(prod);  
> ...
> ```

solution is to adjust the mapping of the collection to be using cascading:

```
<class name="Product">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Category" />
    <property name="Discontinued" />

    <bag name="ProductTypes" 
      lazy="true" inverse="true" batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
     >
      <key column="ProductID" />
      <one-to-many class="NHibernateSample.Models.ProductType,NHibernateSample" />
    </bag>

</class>
```

*(what are all these settings on the `<bag>` - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057362/1679310))*

I would adjust this POCO defintion

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Category { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Discontinued { get; set; }

    //public virtual IList<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    IList<ProductType> _productTypes;
    public virtual IList<ProductType> ProductTypes
    {
        get { return _productTypes ?? (_productTypes = new List<ProductType>()); }
        set { _productTypes = value; }
    }
}
```

*(that is just to be sure that list is initiated either by NHibernate on load or by us in other cases)*

and then we just have to assign both sides

```
 // product
 Product prod = new Product(); 
 prod.Name = "Q3"; prod.Category = "Audi"; 
 prod.Discontinued = false; 

 // product type
 ProductType productType = new ProudctType();
 ...

 // both sides assigned
 prod.ProductTypes.Add(productType);
 productType.Product = prod;

 session.Save(prod);
```

And we also should adjust the mapping to be readonly for value type property

```
<property name="ProductID" insert="false" update="false" />
<many-to-one name="Product" class="Product">
  <column name="ProductID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

To get more details I would not miss this:

- [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158/1679310)